# JavaScript learning resources

Tags: javascript

I am a programmer and I want to learn JavaScript. What are the best resources, and where I can learn from?

Comment: @some: The OP is looking for learning resources, not a reference manual.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687566/learning-javascript-in-one-weekend/2687693#2687693

Comment: @casablanca:That's why I made a comment instead of reply. But a reference manual is very handy when you are learning, thats why I bothered to answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is the latest javascript resource I've discovered:
http://javascript.crockford.com/

Comment: This is probably one of the best places to learn JavaScript (Read The Good Parts too)

Answer (score 0):

Douglas Crockford's [videos](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/) is a must see resource for learning JavaScript. You should also check out [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/).

Answer (score 0):

Visit another question: [Best resources to learn JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript). All the best resources are listed there. Enjoy.

Comment: except the over zealous moderation removed that question, with no forwarding...

Answer (score 0):

I found codeacademy.com to be pretty damn good!